# Angular Provider UseFactory Injecting Array for Unknown Reason

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular provider set up with a custom injection token, which is supposed to inject an `Observable<Array<string>>` but is instead injecting an `Array<Observable<Array<string>>`.

Here's the code:

Injection token:

```js
export const AUTHORIZED_ROUTE_NAMES = new InjectionToken<Observable<Array<string>>>('Names of authorized routes');
```

Provider configuration from app.module.ts:

```js
providers: [
    // everything else
{ provide : AUTHORIZED_ROUTE_NAMES, useFactory: (routeService : RouteService) => routeService.authorizedRouteNames$, deps: [RouteService], multi: true},
    // everything els
]
```

RouteService:

```js
export class RouteService {

  private _authorizedRouteNames$$ : BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>;

  get authorizedRouteNames$() : Observable<Array<string>> {
    return this._authorizedRouteNames$$.asObservable();
  }

  // code that retrieves the values from the api then calls _authorizedRouteNames$$.next() with the result
}
```

This all culminates in an error in the route guard:

```js
export const authorizedRouteGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {

    const authorizedRoutes$ = inject(AUTHORIZED_ROUTE_NAMES);

    // logic logic logic
    const path = /** from the ActivatedRouteSnapshot provided to the function **/

    return authorizedRoutes$
        pipe(
          map((routes) => {
             return routes.indexOf(path) > -1;
          }
        )
}
```

This results in a "authorizedRoutes$.pipe is not a function".

Using the debugger, the value provided by the inject() function is an ARRAY of `Observable<Array<string>>` (aka `Observable<Array<string>>[]`).

I was work around it by injecting it as `unknown`, then casting a second variable, but why is this being injected as an array?

Comment: that happends because of `multi: true`. do you really need it?

Comment: @Andrei that fixed it, thank you. If you want to post it as an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In providers section you've defined a provider as `multi: true`. It means that there will be many providers for that token. As a result they will be injected as an array.

existing examples of intended `multi: true` uses are http interceptors

Comment: That fixed the issue. I had actually put ```multi:true``` BECAUSE I pretty much copied the definition from the HTTP interceptors in the providers array.